# python flask api to asp.net core api

Tags: python, c#, api, asp.net-core-webapi, flask-restful

and greetings.

I am currently trying to integrate a USSD service. I however am stuck with a platform-specific tutorial. the service is written in python flask, while I a developing using asp.net core API. In the tutorial there are certain requirements, I do not understand.

The overview of the connectivity is: [here](https://developers.africastalking.com/docs/ussd/overview)

Below are the explanations of the tutorial.

> We have initialized a brand new Flask app. We have made sure that it’s
> the main app running. Just below that, we have defined a route that
> allows us to actually access our application. We have defined the
> methods that we need which is the GET and POST HTTP methods. We have
> defined a method/function that will be executed when we are accessing
> the route. In this case, we’ve called it ussd_callback. Within the
> method we receive some special parameters that we are getting from the
> Africa’s Talking API:
>
> session_id gets a unique session ID service_code gets your USSD code
> phone_number gets the phone number thats currently accessing the USSD
> text carries the user response as they use the USSD application

with the code

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

response = ""

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ussd_callback():
  global response
  session_id = request.values.get("sessionId", None)
  service_code = request.values.get("serviceCode", None)
  phone_number = request.values.get("phoneNumber", None)
  text = request.values.get("text", "default")
```

under the ussd_callback function, one can return a raw string, like bellow:

```
if text == '':
    response  = "CON What would you want to check \n"
    response += "1. My Account \n"
    response += "2. My phone number"
```

and continue with

```
elif text == '1':
    response = "CON Choose account information you want to view \n"
    response += "1. Account number \n"
    response += "2. Account balance"
```

After which, one can `return response`.

I have created my own solution in ASP.net core 5 API, with the following.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/[controller]/AddNew")]
    public  ActionResult<string> AddNew(string venueId)
    {
      var answer =  "";
      int number = 0;
      if (venueId is null)
      {
        answer = answer + "CON Please select venue:\n 1.Abor \n 2.Owo \n 3.Ugwueme \n 4.Oweli \n 0.Page 2 ";
        return answer;
      }
      bool isReal = Int32.TryParse(venueId, out number);
      if (isReal)
      {
        if (number == 0)
        {
          answer = answer = "CON \n 5.Umuogbo Agu \n 6.Awha Imezi \n 7.Ovoko \n 8.Opatu \n 9.Akiyi Umulokpa";
          return answer;
        }
        else if (number > 9)
        {
          answer = answer + "CON Invalid input, Please select venue:\n 1.Abor \n 2.Owo \n 3.Ugwueme \n 4.Oweli \n 0.Page 2 ";
          return answer;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        answer = answer + "CON Invalid input, Please select venue:\n 1.Abor \n 2.Owo \n 3.Ugwueme \n 4.Oweli \n 0.Page 2 ";
        return answer;
      }
    




        var data_venue = _db.Venues.Where(m => m.Id == number).FirstOrDefault();
      
      if (data_venue is null)
      {
        return NotFound();
      }


      ApiReport data = new ApiReport()
      {
        DateReported = DateTime.Now,
        VenueId = number,
      };
      var data_report = ReportMapping.ApiReport_To_DataReport(data);

      data_report.DateReported = DateTime.Now;
      data_report.PhoneNumber = "000"; 
      _db.Reports.Add(data_report);
       _db.SaveChanges();

      return $"END \n Thank you for informing us about the new case in {data_venue.Name}. \n ";
    }
```

The USSD initially runs fine and shows the base menu, but it will not work if it tries to respond. it is like I am still sending null values into the code. I would love to debug and see the input data myself but this service works with hosted applications.

I feel that I might have the input parameters wrong, or that I am not using proper headers.

Please fam, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What response do you get when trying to call c# API? How are you calling the API?

Comment: The API is being called by the USSD service. it requires are callback link. this link. I provided an API endpoint and it gives me the first menu 

""CON Please select venue:\n 1.Abor \n 2.Owo \n 3.Ugwueme \n 4.Oweli \n 0.Page 2 "

This menu appears if the data parsed is null. It refuses to send in data